# UIWebView zoom script not working

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios7, scroll, zooming

I want to be able to zoom in and scroll to a certain fixed position on a Facebook-webpage in my application. I manage to view the page without problems, but when I try to to zoom or scroll the `UIWebView` nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Code from `ViewController.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/xxxx"]; 
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
    [amba loadRequest:requestURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [amba stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document. body.style.zoom = 999;"];
   CGPoint topOffset = CGPointMake(50, 20); 
   [scrollView setContentOffset:topOffset animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: here is one big mistake: in `viewDidLoad` you have to call `[super viewDidLoad]` at the beginning, NOT at the end.

Comment: I'm sorry but the first thing you need to learn is this has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` so don't use that tag.

Comment: allright i moved up the [super viewdidload], but no change.

Comment: `[super viewDidLoad]` has nothing to do with this. Why are you zooming through JavaScript and not through the scrollview directly? Also, do you have a webview inside a scrollview? That's bad design. A webview is already a scrollview. You can access a webview's scrollview with `webView.scrollview`.

Comment: no I dont have a scrollview, only the webview. okay so with 'webView.scrollview', which code can I use to scroll to a certain place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to put `webView.delegate=self;` in `viewDidLoad`